# Declaring an array of classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, malloc

I am making a game of cards. At the begining I am asking for the number of players. Player is a class.

I was wondering how do I make an array of players.

Right now I have:

```
Player *listofplayers = new Player[size];
```

I get an error saying unknown array size declared.

On the other hand the below is perfectly fine.

```
int *i = new int[size];
```

Can you please explain the difference between the two?? And what the correct declaration is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do that. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Technically, `new Player[size]()` will work and value-initialize them. That's the close one to your first piece, and that's the difference.

Comment: There is no difference between the two, unless there is a problem with the `Player` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the parenthesis:

```
Player *listofplayers = new Player[size];
```

Like Chris said, since you are using C++, you should use a `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Player> listofplayer(size);
// or:
// std::vector<Player> listofplayer;
// listofplayer.resize(size);
```

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem. I mean removing the paranthesis.

Comment: Can you provide the exact the exact error that you are seeing?

Comment: @fatrock92: yes, it does. It answers your questions: "how do I make an array of players" and "what the correct declaration is".

Comment: vectors are a good idea but I wanted to learn pointers more in detail.